Issues were logged in the Issues panel in Chrome Devtools
Running a Google Pagespeed Insights test on my website it lists the following issue under Best Practices:
Issues were logged in the Issues panel in Chrome Devtools
The problem seems to be some 3. party cookies placed by policy.app.cookieinformation.com
I have however contacted cookieinformation.com and they claim they do not place the mentioned cookies.
What can I do?
Is the reported issue false alarm?
Google Pagespeed Insights list the issues, and so does the DevTools in my browser, But if I use incognito mode or when cookieinformation checks, we do not finde the cookies.

I would like to elaborate on the issue.

My website is netsphere.dk. The cookies I have issues with are placed by the Consent Management Platform, Cookie Information. They advise me that the cookies I can see in my DevTools (CookieInformationConfig & CookieInformationConsent_xxx) are used by their cross-domain consent feature. This feature is not active on my website, but Cookie Information has advised me that if a user has visited another website with the feature, the cookies will be placed in their browser. If they visit my website afterward, the cookies communicate with the cookie information JavaScript initiated by my website.

Therefore, they call the issue in Google Pagespeed Insight a "false positive" because my website does not place the cookie. I'm confused as I do not think Google Pagespeed Insight uses cache or stores cookies.

Here is the reply from Cookie Information: The uc.js file communicates with the policy.app.cookieinformation.com domain, which matches the cookie's domain. This is why the browser lists it in the Application tab.
